# How can I set log level used by distutils when using pip?

Tags: python, logging, pip, distutils, python-c-extension

I'm trying to find out what's the reason of `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` after `pip install greenlet`. I'd like to set log level used by distutils so that debug messages like [`log.debug("Unable to find productdir in registry")`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py#l240) would get printed. After looking at [`def parse_command_line(self):`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/dist.py#l423) I thought `pip install --install-option="-vv" greenlet` should work but it doesn't (verbosity is still 1).

How can I do this?

Comment: It might happen that `pip` itself is changing the log level. Have you tried `pip -vv install --install-option="-vv" greenlet`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I started with. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to use the `--global-option="-vv"` switch for `pip install`, which passes the option in between `setup.py` and `install` when invoking `setup.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set DISTUTILS_DEBUG in the environment.

Comment: This environment variable is used only locally [in](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/cmd.py#l186) cmd.py and [in](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/filelist.py#l42) filelist.py modules and does not effect debug level used by [`Log`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/log.py#l14) class in log.py module.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that debug and log were separate things in distutils.  Glad we ripped all that off in favor of simple logging in distutils2.

Comment: You mean distutils2 doesn't use Python standard logging module?

Comment: I mean it simply uses the standard logging module :)