# How to install gevent on Windows?

Tags: python, pip, gevent, libevent

I'm trying to install gevent on Windows. In order to do that, I've downloaded and compiled libevent, then I run `pip install gevent` and get an error: `Please provide path to libevent source with --libevent DIR`. How can I pass the `libevent` option to `setup.py` using `pip`?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

UPD: running `pip install gevent --install-option="--libevent path_to_libevent"` gives the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get a binary installer from http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list

Comment: I need to install gevent to a separate Python environment, and it looks like the binary installer doesn't support it.

Comment: You can try to get the egg http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b1-py2.7-win32.egg which is a zip file that contains 'gevent' package.

Comment: @IvanGromov You **can** install package into virtualenv using binary installer. See [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3271590/95735)

Comment: Current gevent.org official downloads are listed at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent#downloads

Comment: Binary packages for gevent are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gevent

Answer (score 7):

Download the precompiled packages here:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent

This worked for me, python 2.7 32 bit build.

Comment: No precompiled packages are available for `gevent 1.0.1`. =/

Answer (score 7):

[Latest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent) has pre-compilled wheel:

```
pip install gevent==1.1rc1
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass the libevent option to setup.py using pip?

```
c:\pip install --help
(...)
--global-option=GLOBAL_OPTIONS
                      Extra global options to be supplied to the
                      setup.pycall before the install command
```

See [How can I set log level used by distutils when using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8701598/95735)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 64bit Windows, download [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gevent), otherwise installation would fail.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` works for me on Windows 7 with 32-bit Python 2.7. You will need to install a C compiler and add a `disutils.cfg` file to `\Lib\disutils` under your Python install directory. I have [Ming](http://www.mingw.org/) installed and my `disutils.cfg` looks like this:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```