# Python gevent installation error

Tags: python, importerror, gevent

[I installed gevent but the command returns 'ImportError: No module named gevent' Can you please help me debugging this problem? The code works on my Mac. I don't know why it doesn't work on Windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reDIa.png)

Comment: Uninstall gevent and reinstall.  Also, make sure that you are not in a virtual environment, and if so, make sure it is installed there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get a Window's binary installer from: http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list

You may also check [How to install gevent on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499835/how-to-install-gevent-on-windows) for alternate options.